# Odoo15 error while converting odoo11 to Odoo15

Tags: python, odoo-15

I want to covert a module from odoo11 to odoo15. But there is an error with ast.py . I'm using python 3.7

This is the error.

> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ast.py", line 55, in _convert_num
> raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node)) ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Subscript object at
> 0x7fa289f29d10> - - - 2022-01-03 06:41:31,398 35590 INFO ? odoo.http:
> Generating nondb routing

can anyone Familiar with this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the internal models and views of your odoo 11 application in order to run it in odoo version 15.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose odoo11 use python3.6 or older version of python.
Odoo15 use 3.8

You may need to re-develop your module due to version conflict. also **xml** and views/templates are different in odoo15.